# Convergence of $a_n= (7/10+7/10i)^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am new to real analysis and want to prove that $$a_n=\Bigg(\frac{7}{10}(1+i)\Bigg)^n$$ is convergent for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

This is what I have done:

$a_n= (7/10+7/10i)^n \\
= (49/100+2\cdot49/100i-49/100)^n\\
= (98/100i)^n\\
= \Bigg(\frac{-9604}{10000}\Bigg)^n$

By multiplying some of the terms it seems that the sequence converges to $0$, because $\frac{-9604}{10000}$ is less than $1$. Is this a correct approach? I'm not sure if I am allowed to treat sequences this way. My book only convers sequences very briefly.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome and thanks for showing what you have done so far, +1. Your computation of $a_n$ is wrong, indeed $a_n$ is not purely real for any $n$. But you could compute the absolute value $|a_n|$, which is real and smaller than one (but with $8/10$ already it wouldn't work). What can you deduce from it?

Comment: Why did you take square of the value between the parenthesis?

Comment: What is $i$? The complex root of unity?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano Actually, $a_n$ is real for $n$ a multiple of $4$.

Comment: In your expression for $a_n$ how did you go from $a_n = (\frac{7}{10} + \frac{7}{10}i)^n $ to $(\frac{49}{100} + 2\frac{49}{100}i + \frac{49}{100}i^2)^n$? You seem to be saying that $n$ is of the form $2m$? If you assume this then your method is a neat way of going about it.

Comment: yes Jim, I guess that was what I was doing, but wasn't being very organized about it... I guess what I have created is a subsequence? It's all a bit unclear to me

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the correction! The important distinction between "any" and "every"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a somewhat right idea, but the computation is not correct. Verify that $$c:=\left|\frac7{10}(1+i)\right|=\frac7{10}\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\frac{7\sqrt 2}{10}<1$$
because $\left(\frac{7\sqrt 2}{10}\right)^2=\frac{98}{100}<1$.
Then $|a_n|=|a_1^n|=|a_1|^n=c^n\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very clear way of doing it. I guess what I did was find a subsequence where $n$ was a multiple of 4? Could you clarify a bit more where I went wrong? I don't want to repeat my mistake